# profit loss problem

Tags: recreational-mathematics, percentages

A butcher sells $30\ kg$ beef with $40$% profit and sells $24\ kg$ chicken with $75$% profit. The butcher gains same profit from the both sales. What is ($1$ kg chicken price) / ($1$ kg beef price)?

- Since the question says both sales' profits are same, both sales'
  prices are same. Aren't they?

Let's say 1kg beef price is $10b$ and 1kg chicken price is $10c$.

$$30*10b*1.4 = 24*10c*1.75$$

$$420b = 420c$$
$$\frac cb = 1$$ is what I get as the result. But the answer says $\frac56$

What point did I get wrong?

Comment: I am not sure why you have $10$ in those prices, though it makes no difference to the result.  You seem to have equated revenue rather than profit.  If "price" means the price the butcher pays, and profit is based on a percentage increase to that price, then you should be equating would be $30 \times b\times 0.4 = 24 \times c \times 0.75$ but that would give you yet another answer, which would also be the answer if "price" is the price charged by the butcher and profit is a percentage share of that charged price.

Comment: Using equation $30b \times 0.4=24c \times 0.75$ you get $12b=18c$, so $c/b=2/3$.

Comment: @Tavasanis but the answer says 5/6

Comment: @Tavasanis That's the ratio for the costs. We need the ratio for the prices. See the solution below.

Comment: @JohnDouma The original problem asks for chicken *price* and beef *price*. I understand "price" the sum a customer pays, not the cost the butcher pays. Henry gave such alternatives.

Comment: @Tavasanis We are given profit which is price minus cost. A profit of $40\%$, for example, means $40\%$ over the cost. You need both. If you look at my solution below you get the correct ratio for prices. You cannot get the exact price because there are four unknowns and only three pieces of information. That is why you will notice that the prices are given in terms of the cost of chicken.

Comment: @JohnDouma I agree with the elaboration you give in the answer. But everything would be clearer if the wording was "What is (1 kg chicken cost) / (1 kg beef cost) for the butcher?".

Comment: @Tavasanis The write-up is intended to help the person posting, not spell everything out like he is a complete moron. For example, I expect everyone here to be able to divide $P_c$ by $P_b$ to get $\frac{5}{6}$ and I expect everyone to know that profit is price minus cost.

Answer (score 1):

We are given profit so we must consider prices and costs. Let $P_b, P_c, C_b$ and $C_c$ be the prices and costs of beef and chicken, respectively.

Then we are told that we make $40\%$ profit on the sale of beef and $75\%$ profit on the sale of chicken. We are also told the total profits are equal so we get $$30(0.4C_b)=24(.75)C_c\implies 12C_b=18C_c\implies C_b=\frac{3}{2}C_c$$

The profit on beef is $$P_b-C_b=P_b-\frac{3}{2}C_c=\frac{2}{5}\cdot\frac{3}{2}C_c$$ which imples $$P_b=\frac{21}{10}C_c$$

Likewise, the profit on chicken is $$P_c-C_c=\frac{3}{4}C_c$$ which implies $$P_c=\frac{7}{4}C_c$$

Dividing $P_c$ by $P_b$ gives the result.